# Error message "500 OOPS: vsftpd: refusing to run with writable root inside chroot()"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ftp

I want to setup an anonymous only FTP server (able to upload files). Here is my configuration file:

```
listen=YES

anonymous_enable=YES
anon_root=/var/www/ftp

local_enable=YES
write_enable=YESr.

anon_upload_enable=YES
anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES

xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES

chroot_local_user=YES

dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
pam_service_name=vsftpd
```

But when I try to connect it:

```
kan@kan:~$ ftp yxxxng.bej
Connected to yxxx.
220 (vsFTPd 2.3.5)
Name (yxxxg.bej:kan): anonymous
331 Please specify the password.
Password:
500 OOPS: vsftpd: refusing to run with writable root inside chroot()
Login failed
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: This line looks wrong: write_enable=YESr.

Comment: Add allow_writeable_chroot=YES and restart it.

Comment: allow_writeable_chroot=YES indeed solved the problem !

Comment: allow_writeable_chroot=YES does not supported in VSFTPD2.3.5.3 ,  I had a requirement of anonymous user accessing root directories and always had this error while logging in . after brainstorming was able to get rid of the error by adding FTP_USER=anonymous   to config file . useradd anonymous and creating the FTPUSER group and adding the anonymous  user to the group  sudo groupadd ftpuser sudo useradd -g ftpuser -d /XXX anonymous sudo chmod 0777 /XXX

Answer (score 63, accepted):

This blog here points out how to fix this problem.

http://www.mikestechblog.com/joomla/operating-systems-section/operating-systems-ubuntu/155-500-oops-vsftpd-refusing-to-run-with-writable-root-inside-chroot.html

The issue being that the user's root directory is writable.  The Frontier Group provides you with a fix on vsFTPd.

Here are the steps to be taken (copy paste from the tutorial, in case the link dies)

1. login as root (or sudo..) and do the following:
2. vi /etc/vsftpd.conf and add the following
   allow_writeable_chroot=YES
3. sudo service vsftpd restart

Comment: My company's firewall says the link leads to a "criminal activity site"...

Comment: This is not Off Topic... I wouldn't recommed this suggestion, though, and stick with the 'security' recommendation. All you have to do is ``chmod ugo-w /path/to/directory``

Comment: apt-repo doesn't have (deb) packages for 'raring'

Comment: Arod posted the answer! "All you have to do is chmod ugo-w /path/to/directory"

Comment: @blo0p3r : I've already put `allow_writeable_chroot=YES` in my vsftpd.conf file and I steel the message. I need the write permission for annons (local site)....

Comment: Yeah but what's the security implication of a writable chroot root??

Comment: `W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/thefrontiergroup/vsftpd/ubuntu/dists/wheezy/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/thefrontiergroup/vsftpd/ubuntu/dists/wheezy/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.`

It can't be an answer

Comment: @arod then how will the user be able to write to his own directory?

Comment: @PineappleUndertheSea a subdirectory can be used ...

Comment: allow_writeable_chroot=YES and restart vsftpd. That is all

Comment: The vsftpd in ubuntu distro IGNORES `allow_writeable_chroot` option and and the one version presented here is no longer available. This answer is no longer helpful.

Comment: Uhh WTF. Do not install some random persons' repository from the internet. Just add the allow_writeable_chroot=YES option, that is sufficient!

Comment: Adding allow_writeable_chroot=YES worked for me! thank you!

Comment: Basically, create a subdirectory like `/var/www/ftp/files`, which has the write permissions. Then take the write permissions with `sudo chmod a-w /var/www/ftp` away from the root ftp directory.

Comment: I think user *user2284570* means *"I still get the message"* (not *"I steel the message"*).

Comment: The link is broken (404).